# Pseudocounts and Hypergeometric Distribution

Tags: p-value, hypergeometric-distribution

How can I add pseudocounts to hypergeometric distribution to calculate p-values.

By Pseudocounts I mean: A pseudocount is an amount (not generally an integer, despite its name) added to the number of observed cases in order to change the expected probability in a model of those data, when not known to be zero

I am using `hypergeom` in python and it receives four parameters
    [`hypergeom(k,M,n,N)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html)

if I want to and c as pseudocounts to avoid zero counts, how can I do it keeping the same idea of hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: Hi, welcome. 1) Please link to the relevant Python documentation of `hypergeom`. 2) Please also say a few words on what "pseudocounts" are supposed to represent. – *Reviewer*